# Fluid grid with divs - keep aspect ratio

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a simple fluid grid going with a large block on the left and two smaller on the right, stacked. I'm trying to get the right blocks to be the same height as the left. I'm using the padding-top percentage trick (i.e. `padding-top: 61.643835616%;`) to get the divs to keep their aspect ratio. It is very close the being equal heights but the right is still a little off. It gets worse if you size down.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to handle this?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XV9Zn/)

Comment: Are you trying for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FTL93/2/ where they are touching and so forth? Do you have a fixed height and width for every element? Or is there another idea?

Comment: No, like they are in my jsfiddle demo. They would need to be laid out in a grid, be fluid width/height, but the two on the right need to be as tall as the large on the left. The width is controlled by the column they are in and the height is dynamic with the aspect ratio trick.